# Compare data from 2 sheets and find mismatches

Tags: vba, excel, comparison

I've got 3 sheets in my workbook, 2 of them contain similar information - the same columns but the data may vary.

So, in column A there is list of units, then in column B there is contents, in column C - temperature, and in column D - destination.

What I'm trying to do is compare the data from 2 sheets to show all the mismatches in Sheet 3 - ie if unit number (A) matches, look for mismatches in contents (B), temperature (c) and destination (D). If any of that data is different, copy it side by side from two sheets onto the third one.

Then, compare unit numbers - if a number is found in one sheet but not in the other, highlight it in red, if the numbers from both lists match, highlight in yellow OR leave color the same.

This is what I've got so far:

```
Option Explicit

Const MySheet1 As String = "Sheet1" 'list 1

Const MySheet2 As String = "Sheet2" 'list 2

Const MySheet3 As String = "Sheet3" 'output sheet

Sub CompareLists()

    Dim List1() As Variant, List2() As Variant
    Dim LC1 As Long, LC2 As Long, ORow As Long
    Dim Loop1 As Long, Loop2 As Long, Loop3 As Long

    ORow = 4
    With ThisWorkbook
        LC1 = .Sheets(MySheet1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
        LC2 = .Sheets(MySheet2).UsedRange.Rows.Count
        List1 = .Sheets(MySheet1).Range("A1:D" & LC1).Value
        List2 = .Sheets(MySheet2).Range("A1:D" & LC2).Value

For Loop2 = 2 To LC2

    If Len(List2(Loop2, 3)) > 0 Then
        List2(Loop2, 3) = Trim(List2(Loop2, 3))
    End If

Next Loop2

        With .Sheets(MySheet3)
            .Cells.ClearContents
            .Range("A1").Value = "Mismatched Records"
            .Range("A3").Value = "Unit Number"
            .Range("B2").Value = MySheet1
            .Range("E2").Value = MySheet2
            .Range("B3").Value = "Type"
            .Range("C3").Value = "Required Temperature"
            .Range("D3").Value = "Final Destination"
            .Range("E3").Value = "Type"
            .Range("F3").Value = "Required Temperature"
            .Range("G3").Value = "Final Destination"
        End With
        For Loop1 = 2 To LC1
            For Loop2 = 2 To LC2
                If Trim(List1(Loop1, 1)) = Trim(List2(Loop2, 1)) Then
                    For Loop3 = 2 To 4
                        If Trim(List1(Loop1, Loop3)) <> Trim(List2(Loop2, Loop3)) Then
                            With .Sheets(MySheet3)
                                .Range("A" & ORow).Value = List1(Loop1, 1)
                                .Range("B" & ORow).Value = List1(Loop1, 2)
                                .Range("C" & ORow).Value = List1(Loop1, 3)
                                .Range("D" & ORow).Value = List1(Loop1, 4)
                                .Range("E" & ORow).Value = List2(Loop2, 2)
                                .Range("F" & ORow).Value = List2(Loop2, 3)
                                .Range("G" & ORow).Value = List2(Loop2, 4)
                            End With
                            ORow = ORow + 1
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next Loop3
                    Exit For
                Else
                    DoEvents
                End If
            Next Loop2
        Next Loop1
    End With

    MsgBox "Finished", vbInformation, "Done!"

End Sub
```

But the code doesn't work properly - ie it doesn't list existing mismatches on the output sheet and also doesn't highlight mismatching unit numbers in red.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I'm seeing is that your data comparison is predicated on the key columns matching. If there is a value in Sheet1's column A that does not exist in Sheet2's column A then the remaining values from each worksheet's column B through D are not checked and nothing gets reported. With your judicious use of `Exit For`, the [For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) that compares the key column should never reach its termination. If it does then there is something in Sheet1 's column A that does not exist in Sheet2's column A and that should be reported.

```
Option Explicit

Const MySheet1 As String = "Sheet1" 'list 1
Const MySheet2 As String = "Sheet2" 'list 2
Const MySheet3 As String = "Sheet3" 'output sheet

Sub CompareLists2()

    Dim List1 As Variant, List2 As Variant
    Dim LC1 As Long, LC2 As Long, ORow As Long
    Dim Loop1 As Long, Loop2 As Long, Loop3 As Long

    ORow = 4
    With ThisWorkbook
        LC1 = .Sheets(MySheet1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
        LC2 = .Sheets(MySheet2).UsedRange.Rows.Count
        List1 = .Sheets(MySheet1).Range("A1:D" & LC1).Value
        List2 = .Sheets(MySheet2).Range("A1:D" & LC2).Value

        For Loop2 = 2 To LC2
            List2(Loop2, 3) = Trim(List2(Loop2, 3))
        Next Loop2

        With .Sheets(MySheet3)
            .Cells.ClearContents
            .Range("A1").Value = "Mismatched Records"
            .Range("A3").Value = "Unit Number"
            .Range("B2").Value = MySheet1
            .Range("E2").Value = MySheet2
            .Range("B3").Value = "Type"
            .Range("C3").Value = "Required Temperature"
            .Range("D3").Value = "Final Destination"
            .Range("E3").Value = "Type"
            .Range("F3").Value = "Required Temperature"
            .Range("G3").Value = "Final Destination"
        End With

        For Loop1 = 2 To LC1
            For Loop2 = 2 To LC2
                If Trim(List1(Loop1, 1)) = Trim(List2(Loop2, 1)) Then
                    For Loop3 = 2 To 4
                        If Trim(List1(Loop1, Loop3)) <> Trim(List2(Loop2, Loop3)) Then
                            With .Sheets(MySheet3)
                                .Range("A" & ORow).Value = List1(Loop1, 1)
                                .Range("B" & ORow).Value = List1(Loop1, 2)
                                .Range("C" & ORow).Value = List1(Loop1, 3)
                                .Range("D" & ORow).Value = List1(Loop1, 4)
                                .Range("E" & ORow).Value = List2(Loop2, 2)
                                .Range("F" & ORow).Value = List2(Loop2, 3)
                                .Range("G" & ORow).Value = List2(Loop2, 4)
                            End With
                            ORow = ORow + 1
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next Loop3
                    Exit For
                ElseIf Loop2 = LC2 Then
                    'last loop and no match
                    'this reports sheet1 missing from sheet2
                    With .Sheets(MySheet3)
                        .Range("A" & ORow).Value = List1(Loop1, 1)
                        .Range("B" & ORow).Value = List1(Loop1, 2)
                        .Range("C" & ORow).Value = List1(Loop1, 3)
                        .Range("D" & ORow).Value = List1(Loop1, 4)
                    End With
                    ORow = ORow + 1
                End If
            Next Loop2
        Next Loop1

        'add a reverse loop for Sheet2 column A keys missing from Sheet1's column A
        For Loop2 = 2 To UBound(List2, 1)
            For Loop1 = 2 To UBound(List1, 1)
                If Trim(List1(Loop1, 1)) = Trim(List2(Loop2, 1)) Then
                    Exit For
                ElseIf Loop1 = UBound(List1, 1) Then
                    'last loop and no match
                    'this reports sheet2 missing from sheet1
                    With .Sheets(MySheet3)
                        .Range("A" & ORow).Value = List2(Loop2, 1)
                        .Range("E" & ORow).Value = List2(Loop2, 2)
                        .Range("F" & ORow).Value = List2(Loop2, 3)
                        .Range("G" & ORow).Value = List2(Loop2, 4)
                    End With
                    ORow = ORow + 1
                End If
            Next Loop1
        Next Loop2

    End With

    MsgBox "Finished", vbInformation, "Done!"

End Sub
```

I've added a half-reverse loop to also catch keys from Sheet2's column A that are not found in Sheet1's column A.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've modified my code to include your adjustments. But now it comes back to me with an "Expected array" error with a reference to this line:                                                                                        'add a reverse loop for Sheet2 column A keys missing from Sheet1's column A
    For Loop2 = 2 To UBound(Loop2, 1)                                                               Can you please advise what the problem might be here?                                       Thanks

Comment: My apologies. I missed a couple of things transcribing into your code vernacular. I've done a full page rewrite and edited by response to include it above. btw, you write nice code!

Comment: Thank you! Will test it tomorrow :)