# Comparing two sheets, if the rows of information isn't on both sheets, extract to separate sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to excel, and was wondering how to compare information on both sheets, `query` and `query (1)`, and if the information is not on both sheets, I would like to extract it to another sheet. So far this is what I got:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim sh_extract, sh_tocopy As Worksheet
    Set sh_extract = wb.Worksheets("query")
    Set sh_extract = wb.Worksheets("query (1)")
    Set sh_tocopy = wb.Worksheets("extracted")
```

Comment: Note that `Dim sh_extract, sh_tocopy As Worksheet` only declares the second as `Worksheet` you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim sh_extract As Worksheet, sh_tocopy As Worksheet`. •  Aso you set `Set sh_extract` twice which makes the first useless. • Try starting with a loop going through your sheet and compare each line.

Comment: Oh ok thank you, but I was wondering what commands to use to compare and extract the rows that don't match. I think I have an idea such as "If not" statements @Pᴇʜ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two sheets and find differences, copy to third sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32648250/compare-two-sheets-and-find-differences-copy-to-third-sheet)